# Custom day header depending on the events of the day

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar 5 timeGrid view and I'm trying to add the number of events of the day into each day header.

I saw we can use the `dayHeaderContent` like that

```js
calendarOptions = {
  dayHeaderContent({ date, text, view }) {
    return text + ' suffix';
  }
  // ...
}
```

This adds ' suffix' after each day header.

We can access the events through the api, but the day header is called just once and before receiving the events from the sources.
One can call `api.render()` to trigger the day header rendering, but that means almost everything gets rendered twice. Additionally I don't see when render() could be called. From an event source callback, events seem not updated just after the `successCallback`.

Example:

```js
calendarOptions = {
  eventSources: [
    {
      id: 'time-entries',
      events(fetchInfo, successCallback) {
        const events = getTheEvents();
        successCallback(events);
        fcApi.render(); // dayHeaderContent still shows the previous events
      },
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

**How can I effectively show the number of events on each day header ?**